# How to call IntentService from WakefulBroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, intentservice, android-broadcastreceiver

I have an `IntentService` defined as below:

```
<service android:name=".service.AppService" android:process=":app_process" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />
```

I have a `WakefulBroadcastReceiver` that receives some data and I would like to call my already running service above. The service above is always running, even if it is killed, it restarts. How can I pass messages to that?

I read the following:

http://www.mysamplecode.com/2011/10/android-intentservice-example-using.html

http://www.truiton.com/2014/09/android-service-broadcastreceiver-example/

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

I tried to do a `startService`, `PendingIntent` among other things and nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, remember that an IntentService works in a different worker thread, there for it's not possible to have intercommunication with the Activity that invoked it. That's why mostly we use them for synchronization on background where feedback to the user is not needed. However, if you want to pass some information to the Activity, you have to use a BroadcastReceiver as you said, and from there create the Intent that will send "data" to the Activity.

Going back to your question, you have to add the service and the receiver in your AndroidManifest.xml inside the `<application>` tag

```
<service android:name=".AppService"
  android:enabled="true"/>
<receiver android:name=".WakefulBroadcastReceiver" >
</receiver>
```

Then in your Activity launch the service like this (whenever you need it, in the onCreate, or in a button listener)

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
WakefulBroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new WakefulBroadcastReceiver();
registerReceiver(broadcastReceiver, filter);
```

In your BroadcastReceiver you override the onReceive() method like this:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    // HERE IS WHERE YOU RECEIVE THE INFORMATION FROM THE INTENTSERVICE, FROM HERE YOU CAN START AN ACTIVITY OR WHATEVER YOU AIM
    Toast.makeText(context, "IntentService Broadcasting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Also in the same BroadcastReceiver add this variable that identifies the intentfilter:

```
public static final String ACTION_RESP = "MY_FILTER_NAME"
```

In your IntentService class you have to override the onHandleIntent() method like this:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String msg = intent.getStringExtra("MSG");
    Intent broadcast = new Intent();
    broadcast.setAction(WakefulBroadcastReceiver.ACTION_RESP);
    broadcast.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
    broadcast.putExtra("MSG", resultTxt);
    // HERE IS WHERE YOU SEND THE INFORMATION YOU LOADED TO THE APP
    sendBroadcast(broadcast);
}
```

I have a demo project in my GitHub account here, where I use bound and unbound services and IntentServices:
https://github.com/isaacurbina/PermissionsAndServices

I hope it helps.

Kind regards!

Comment: One more question if I may: I'm trying to have a web socket run in a service. Is an `IntentService` the best way based on what you're describing here seems no?

Comment: An IntentService is meant for not so long operations, for long operations you can use a Service (either bound or unbound) a JobScheduler or a SyncAdapter, depends more on what you want to do but any of those will do.

Answer (score 0):

You can write this in your class that extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver :

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Intent gcmIntent = new Intent(context, MessageService.class);
    gcmIntent.putExtras(intent.getExtras());
    startWakefulService(context, gcmIntent);
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
}
```

And write this in your class that extend IntentService :

```
@Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        //do sth with that data
        MessageReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
```